# Easy way to add an additional type to a variable

Tags: typescript

I have a simple typescript code:

```
let foo = document.createElement('div');
foo.id='foo';
foo=null;
```

TS complains correctly that the cleanup line is not valid because foo should be only a div.

```
let foo: null | HTMLDivElement = document.createElement('div');
foo.id='foo';
foo=null;
```

Would be ok. But this is really cumbersome. Is there a nice solution like my non working example?

```
let foo: & null = document.createElement('div');
foo.id='foo';
foo=null;
```

Comment: How does the "clean-up" work in this case?

Comment: `createElement` was an only an example. Setting the variable to null should be a marker in the code, that the object (can be a complex data holding object in my real code) should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends if you have the `strict` (or `strictNullChecks`) flag enabled in your `tsconfig.json` file or not. If you do have this flag, then you must add the `| null` part to the type of `foo`. If you don't have this flag, TypeScript shouldn't complain.

- [Example with `strictNullChecks` enabled, TS error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jBcEASAVAsgGQCIEsBuAoqALYgB2kAvBACYwDGArqRQHT0BOIAhmCESBZgAFAHIa%20UQEoA3AChYMVjhqVRi0fMWUyjYMBlA)
- [Example with `strictNullChecks` disabled, no TS error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jBcEASAVAsgGQCIEsBuAoqALYgB2kAvBACYwDGArqRQHT0BOIAhmCESBZgAFAHIa%20UQEoA3AChYMVjhqVRi0fMWUyjYMBlA)

That being said, I would recommend using the `strict` mode, it **really** helps avoiding runtime errors due to `null` or `undefined` references. I don't know how the rest of your code looks, but IMO you shouldn't have to "clear" the reference by assigning `null` to it, nowadays garbage collection is strong enough to handle the "free unused memory" step.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is contrived - I presume, so I will assume you really need to assign null to some variable to clean it:

Maybe this code would be better for "cleaning"?

```
let foo = document.createElement('div');
foo.id='foo';
(foo as any) = null;
```

Comment: I want clean typing with small effort.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clean typing' ?

Comment: In my code it is ok that `foo` could be `null` and this should be known to TS.